# Count total number of real-time signals received inside signal handler

Tags: c, signals

I am writing a signal handler in a server where I need to receive all the signals sent by clients before returning to the main program of the server. The signals are real-time in nature. My code is given below:

```
static void handlerB(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context){


    id[count] = info->si_pid; 
    printf("A's process ID: %d \n", (int)id[count]);
    count++;

    kill (pid, SIGCONT);

}
```

I need to wait for all the sent signals to be received the handler, so that "count" is set to the total number of signals received, before proceeding to sending SIGCONT to the main program. In other words, the handler will be called only once during execution of the program. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you declare `count`?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).